# codelgniter error: Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, codeigniter

on running controller on localhost. it shows

> **Warning**: include(): **Failed to open stream**: No such file or
>   directory in (C:\wamp\www\Codelgniter\system\core\Exceptions.php)

**Added From Comment:**

signUpController

```
<?php 

class SignupController extends CI_Controller { 

    public function index() { 

       $this->load->view('signUpView'); 
    } 

}
```

**signUpView**

```
<?php 

    include 'header.php'; 

    include 'footer.php';

?>
```

Comment: show your include function

Comment: **SignUpController** <?php

class SignupController extends CI_Controller{
   
    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('signUpView');
    }
}
?>

Comment: **signUpView** <?php include 'header.php'; ?>


<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>

Comment: there is no include on here

Comment: You should be using `$this->load->view('header')` rather than include.

Comment: answer is posted. check below

Comment: This is not a Codeigniter problem at all. You don't have your include_path set up correctly in php.ini.

Comment: When some additional material is requested by comments, you need to **edit** the question, but don't post the code in the comments !!

Comment: @arunchoudhary Did any of the Answer help you?

Comment: @wolfgang1983 No..but i had reinstall the codeigniter in localhost and then its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have included a leading / in your file path. The / makes it start at the top of your filesystem. Note: filesystem path, not Web site path (you're not accessing it over HTTP). You can use a relative path with include_once (one that doesn't start with a leading /).

You can change it to this:

```
include_once 'headerSite.php';
```

That will look first in the same directory as the file that's including it (i.e. C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\ in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Use `APPPATH` when include file

**In signUpView**

```
$head = APPPATH."view/header.php");
include($head);

$foot = APPPATH."view/footer.php");
include($foot);
```

Or **In Controller**

```
class SignupController extends CI_Controller
{ 
    public function index() 
    { 
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('signUpView');  
        $this->load->view('footer'); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: @arunchoudhary any errors??

Answer (score 0):

> **Codeigniter 3** versions: First letter of **class name** must be upper case.
>    And same with **file name** `Signupcontroller.php`

On codeigniter you do not need to use include to load your views you can just use the $this->load->view() way as shown below.

They way to load view in controllers.

```
<?php 

class Signupcontroller extends CI_Controller { 

    public function index() { 

       $this->load->view('header'); 
       $this->load->view('signUpView'); 
       $this->load->view('footer'); 
    } 

}
```

Or if you need to load a view into a view then on the signUpView

**application > views > signUpView.php**

```
<?php $this->load->view('header');?> 

signUpView content

<?php $this->load->view('footer');?>
```

User guide: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Both user guide versions found here now: http://www.codeigniter.com/docs